# Babel 7 + Inversify 4 + WebPack 4 - Unexpected character '@' on @inject

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, inversifyjs

I have a typescript Vue SPA project where I use [Inversify](http://inversify.io/).

I used *awesome-typescript-loader* for compiling my typescript source code; now I want to switch to *Babel* but when I compile my application *webpack* raise this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (38:25) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | _inherits(ReportService, _BaseService);
>   | >   function ReportService(@inject(TYPES.Urls)
>   |   urls) {
>   |     var _this;
>   @ ./app/Ioc/container.ts 6:0-54 14:39-52
>   @ ./app/startup.ts

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "test/*": [ "test/*" ],
      "@/*": [ "app/*" ]
    },
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ], // es6 minimum required for Promise
    "target": "es6", // Required for vuetify
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true, // Required for @Component for Vue
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const config = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/startup.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot", "dist"),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader",
                exclude: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
                ]
            },

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@': path.join(__dirname, 'app')
        },
        extensions: ['.vue', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all",
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: -10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use *awesome-typescript-loader* chained to *babel-loader*

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'awesome-typescript-loader']
}
```

and remove the unnecessary babel plugin and presets it work.

Comment: Do class, method and property decorators work? If so, maybe babel doesn't support transpiling decorators on function arguments yet, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes decorators works. Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, which I solved by adding additional plugin "babel-plugin-transform-function-parameter-decorators", however in my case this solved the issue only partially because now even though transpilation succeeds, I get "Missing required inject or multiInject annotation in: argument 0 when using constructor injection"

Answer (score 12):

That's is a really annoying issue of `@babel/preset-typescript` implementation:
it strips types and doesn't emit the relative Metadata in the output code.

The only thing that helped is [babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata)

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to get inversify working. Your answer saved me.

Comment: @AbdouOuahib u're welcome. Yeah, it was quite desperate case :)

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been playing around with babel settings all day, this simple change made it all work perfectly!